# store variables to order them in another android layer

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm in existential crisis on how store variable to order them in another android layer.

## Example

I have five (5) android layers, and store variables from first and second layer to show the variable in the last layer (5).

**Tip:**
This layers is fragments.

Capture(1)(2)..Jump Data to (5)

Bundle isn't functional for me, as I'm only working from fragment to fragment.

Does this method work with Shared Preferences?

Is there another method?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell if "This method make with Shared Preferences?" means you have or you haven't tried using SharedPreferences, but I'll assume you haven't.

SharedPreferences store in key-value pairs. So I think this would be a great option for you to use.

There's many great tutorials, but a great one is this:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fJEFZ6EOM9o

And here is a link to the docs for more:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html

Hope it helps :)

Comment: i tested shared preferences i don't solve my problem, i need traspasing the variables in layers

Comment: Still not sure what you mean exactly, but you should be able to store most variables in SharedPreferences. If you need to store multiple items that are easily accessible, you could save a HashMap in the shared preference

Answer (score 0):

## Using shared preferences

Yes, you can store your data in shared preferences. You can use the *default shared preferences* to save the data in layers **one** and **two**, like below:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = SharedPreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
prefs.edit().putInt("my value", someValue).apply();
```

Then in the fifth layer (fragment), just read the value:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = SharedPreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
int myValue = prefs.getInt("my value");
```

Adapt the code to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Shure finally learn to use Shared Preferences to Jump Data to wish layout

ORIGIN LAYOUT

//DECLARE VARIABLES

```
   //Shared Preferences
public static final String SHARED_PREFS_FILE = "sharedPrefs";
public static final String KEY_TEXT ="text";
```

//IN THE ITEM TO IMPLEMENT THE METHOD

```
 newListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
     //IN MY ONITEMCLICK

        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getContext().getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFS_FILE, 0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putString(KEY_TEXT, "string_to_update");
        editor.commit();

    }
});
```

//LAYER TO RECEIVE DATA

PUT IN onNewCreate

@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view =inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_nueva_medicion, container, false);

```
    //SHOW DATA
    muestraCliente = view.findViewById(R.id.textvCliente);
    ShowClienteFragment scf = new ShowClienteFragment();
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getContext().getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFS_FILE, 0);
    cliente = sharedPreferences.getString(KEY_TEXT,"");
    showData.setText(cliente);

    return view;
}
```